# Not able to exit the loop in python

Tags: python

I am very new to Python and trying to execute below code. The program is to calculate compound interest.

I created basic program and passed values as argument and it worked.
Later I created user input program and it worked.

Now when I tried to handle negative or 0 values I am not able to exit program

```
def CompI(amt, r, t):
    return amt * (pow((1 + r / 100), t)) 

print("Enter Amount")
amt = int(input())
if amt<0 or amt == 0:
    print("Invalid Input")
    exit()

print("Enter rate")
r = int(input())
if r<0 or r == 0:
    print("Invalid Input")
    exit()

print("Enter Time")
t = int(input())
if t<0 or t == 0:
    print("Invalid Input")
    exit()

CI = CompI(amt, r, t)
print("Result is", CI)
```

---

Result

---

Enter Amount
0
Invalid Input
Enter rate

---

when I enter amount as 0 it displays error message and further ask me to enter rate.

Comment: Your code and your error message do not match. Please post your **actual** code.

Comment: How's your code working? Can you please share right code. It is not even indented.

Comment: error shows `CompI.exit()` but you don't have it in code. You shows wrong code or you runs wrong file.

Comment: I have corrected the result and error message

Answer (score 0):

maybe try `import sys` and then use `sys.exit()` .

Comment: Tried your suggestion and it worked correctly with an exception. Please have a look to guide further.

Comment: Enter Amount
0
Invalid Input

An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit



C:\Users\rbrijbhushan.EAD\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:3334: UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
  warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)

Comment: For positive scenario also same exception is coming.                                                                                         Enter Amount
10000

An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit

Comment: are you running this from the python prompt?

Comment: Running it on Anaconda - Jupyter

Comment: can you upload your entire code? is there a loop somewhere? if you are using exit like you do now, the last part might never be reached.

Comment: import sys
def CompI(amt, r, t):
    return amt * (pow((1 + r / 100), t)) 

print("Enter Amount")
amt = int(input())
if amt<0 or amt == 0:
    print("Invalid Input")
    sys.exit()

print("Enter rate")
r = int(input())
if r<0 or r == 0:
    print("Invalid Input")
sys.exit()

print("Enter Time")
t = int(input())
if t<0 or t == 0:
    print("Invalid Input")
sys.exit()
    
CI = CompI(amt, r, t)
print("Result is", CI)

Comment: Above is the small program I have written nothing extra